# QJsonObject and international characters

Tags: json, qt, character-encoding

I have problem with `QJsonObject` character encoding. `QJsonObject::toJson()` returns string with international characters as hex values:

```
s:  "żółć"
obj:  QJsonObject({"s":"żółć"})
doc:  QJsonDocument({"s":"żółć"})
JSON:  "{\n    \"s\": \"\xC5\xBC\xC3\xB3\xC5\x82\xC4\x87\"\n}\n"
```

Code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString s = "żółć";
    qDebug() << "s: " << s;

    QJsonObject obj;
    obj["s"] = s;
    qDebug() << "obj: " << obj;

    QJsonDocument doc(obj);
    qDebug() << "doc: " << doc;


    qDebug() << "JSON: " << doc.toJson();


    return a.exec();
}
```

How can I get JSON string with international characters?

Comment: No. That is qDebug() in Qt Creator debug output console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884570/qdebug-doesnt-support-unicode-strings-on-windows JSON is good with UNICODE by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `QJsonObject::toJson()` returns string with national characters as hex
>   values

Assuming you meant [`QJsonDocument::toJson()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#toJson) this is not true, `QJsonDocument::toJson()` returns a `QByteArray` encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), this way it is capable of encoding all possible characters, or code points, defined by Unicode. After that, you can send/save the result `QByteArray` to be read and parsed later, and you should be able to get your original string out of it.

So, the HEX characters you are seeing in the debug output are not really there, they are just [`QDebug`'s way of printing `QByteArray`s](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-17):

> Normally, `QDebug` prints the array inside quotes and transforms control
>   or non-US-ASCII characters to their C escape sequences (`\xAB`). This
>   way, the output is always 7-bit clean and the string can be copied
>   from the output and pasted back into C++ sources, if necessary.

You can use [`qDebug().noqoute()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#noquote) to see how your JSON byte array looks like without escaping those characters:

```
qDebug().noquote() << "JSON: " << doc.toJson();
```

Or, you can print it as a `QString` instead:

```
qDebug() << "JSON: " << QString::fromUtf8(doc.toJson());
```

---

#### Note:

It is very bad practice to put non-ascii chars in string literals. You should read them from a resource or an escaped string literal while specifying their encoding (maybe using [`QString::fromUtf8()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8), [`QString::fromUtf16()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf16), ...).

Comment: Regarding string literals in Qt, this is exactly what the [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) macro was made for.

Comment: @MrEricSir , `QStringLiteral` macro was made specifically to generate a `QString` out of a literal at compile time in order to avoid the overhead of generating one at run time. I am not sure if one can safely use locale-dependent non-ascii characters in literals in their source code files when using it. can you confirm that?

Comment: @MrEricSir , since `QStringLiteral` seem to use wide string literals [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h#n139) and [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h#n148), it maybe safe. But I would never expect something like `QString("żółć")` to be safe. Am I right with that?

Comment: As long as you're using an up-to-date compiler, `QStringLiteral` should always perform the correct conversion. I believe the `QString` constructor that takes a string literal will only convert from UTF-8, which may or may not be what's desired.

Comment: Ok, so how should I get user input with international characters and build JSON with them?

Comment: @Sajmplus , there is no problem with that. The problem we are discussing here applies to string literals. using `QLineEdit::text()` to get a `QString` for user input for example is sure to be alright.

Comment: And how can I make `QNetworkAccessManager::post` request to WebAPI using encoded `QByteArray`? When I POST with curl `Żółć` it seems to be ok, but when I post UTF-8 encoded `\xC5\xBB\xC3\xB3\xC5\x82\xC4\x87` i get `????` as reply.